# porting isnan to c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

When I'm switching the compiler version from gcc 4.6 to gcc 4.8 I get the following error
error: call of overloaded 'isnan(double)' is ambiguous.

This is because in c++11 there are differend function declarations:
C: int isnan(double)
C++11: bool isnan(double)

from [cpluplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isnan/):

- In C, this is implemented as a macro that returns an int value. The type of x shall be float, double or long double.
- In C++, it is implemented with function overloads for each floating-point type, each returning a bool value.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you calling it? Show us the context.

Comment: juanchoupanza suggestion worked. I had declared using namespace std before, but I had to prepend it anyway to the isnan call because it was source of ambiguity.

Comment: That's exactly what's wrong with `use namespace std` everywhere.

Comment: May this work as a lesson. Now go forth and stop ab`using namespace std`.

Answer (score 14):

Although you can mitigate this problem by not saying `using namespace std;` everywhere, you can avoid it by being explicit about using `std::isnan`:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  double x = ....;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << std::isnan(x) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This approach will surely work but it will not be appropriate to remove "using namespace std"  in a large codebase as it may need too many changes.

Comment: @wazza It will be more appropriate than leaving the code broken. `using namespace std;` is a recipe for trouble. I think time spend purging it from code is time well spent.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 there should not be ambiguity between the C and C++ isnan function. It works as expected, even with `using namespace std`.

Please check that you are **not** doing both `#include <math.h>` and `#include <cmath>`. Only include cmath.

Alternatively, perhaps you somewhere have in your project a user-defined `isnan(double)` function, or some header includes "math.h".

Also please note, that if one wants to write generic code, it is incorrect to use the 'std::' prefix on the math functions as it breaks the argument dependent lookup (ADL). (Because the C++ standard does not allow injecting functions in the std:: namespace)

The correct use for `isnan` in generic code is `using std::isnan;` then use just `isnan` on the variables. Otherwise your code with user defined floating point types such as for arbitrary precision, automatic differentiation and such wont work. The root of this inconsistency is that the built in types such as `double` do not reside in the namespace `std` but the functions that operate on them do.

Comment: It's just `<cmath>`, not `<cmath.h>`.